# Capacitor voltage across two different sources

Tags: voltage, capacitor, current, resistors

Assume I have a capacitor.

I'd like to know what the voltage across the capacitor would be if I connect two DC sources to its terminals. I performed a simulation but didn't get any understanding.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fnJg6H.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I just want to understand what would the voltage on the capacitor terminals in the above scenario?

Comment: What did the simulation tell you about the voltages? What is the problem with those values?

Comment: I did the simulation in Falstad circuit simulator. When I placed two DC sources across the capacitor, only one terminal should the right DC voltage on the capacitor. The other terminal even though adding a DC voltage source showed 0V. I observed that, whichever terminal I connected DC source first, showed voltage on that terminal. The other terminal showed 0V only.

Comment: There's 5 volts on one side and 7 volts on the other side. What's unclear about this situation? Also Falstad can't simulate infinities so it does not allow you to connect two ideal voltage sources to an ideal capacitor as current would be infinite for infinitely short time period.

Comment: @Justme, so the voltage across the capacitor will be 2V is it?

Comment: @Justme, Instead of simulation, can you tell me the behaviour of the capacitor at this stage and what would happen to the capacitor if one side of the voltage source falls to 0V?

Comment: You are right with 2V. Capacitor between sources always shows their difference.

Comment: @MichalPodmanický, thank you for the clarification. what would happen to the capacitor if one side of the voltage source falls to 0V?

Comment: Still difference. So if left is 0V then 0V-7V=-7V

Comment: @MichalPodmanický, thank you for the clarification.